# Criar variaveis estaticas em constructor javascript

Tags: javascript, classes, static

Ultimamente estou criando classes javascript definindo o que não quero de seja publico durante o constructor, usando NomeClasse.minhaVariavel ex:

```
class NovaClasse {
  static podeMexer = false
  constructor(){
    NovaClasse.estatica = 'nao me toque'
  }
  retornaEstatica(){ return NovaClasse.estatica }
  seMexeu(){ return NovaClasse.podeMexer }
}
NovaClasse.estatica = 'mexi contigo'
NovaClasse.podeMexer = true
const teste = new NovaClasse()
console.log(
  teste.retornaEstatica(), // continua "não me toque"
  teste.seMexeu() //true. alterou
)
```

Em meus testes percebi que se alterar o valor de uma estatica, a classe será instanciada com os novos valores; é somente essa situação que a forma que venho fazendo procura evitar. No meu modo de pensar, se eu posso alterar sem precisar estender então criar classes perde um pouco o sentido

Como eu não vi nenhum outro exemplo usando essa "técnica" e pra não tornar essa uma pergunta opinativa e ferir as regras do site então ...

Qual são os problemas eu posso ter criando estáticas durante o constructor?

Comment: Na verdade, das duas formas você alterou o valor; porém, `NovaClasse.estatica` você define novamente quando instancia de novo a classe, sobrescrevendo o valor que você acabou de definir. E sim, se usar classes somente com valores estáticos ela perde o sentido mesmo. Elas são um mecanismo para você agrupar informações heterogêneas que pertencem à uma mesma instância. Se é estático é igual para todas, não precisaria da classe.

Comment: Por padrão classes não tem uma propriedade ou método privado logo `static` é publico, existe uma proposta para tal mas ainda em discussão. O que você pode fazer é utilizar `Symbol()` como um **"hack"** para chegar a este comportamento (privado)

Comment: Obrigado, vou procurar entendimento sobre Symbol. Depois acabei observando que se alterar a propriedade na classe depois de coisas instanciadas, altera também as instâncias, o que cai por terra minha intenção de proteger as variáveis. Acho que não cabe mais apontamentos nessa pergunta, o moderador pode encerrá-la